# Shorthand for PowerShell's `ForEach -Parallel`

Tags: foreach, parallel-processing, powershell-3.0, parallel.foreach, shorthand

In a PowerShell workflow, the following is valid:

```
$strings='one','two','three'
foreach -parallel($string in $strings)
{
    "Hello: $string"
}
```

A shorhand way of writing this (without the parallel piece) would be:

```
$strings='one','two','three'
$strings | `
%{
    "Hello: $_"
}
```

Is there a way to use the shorthand version, specifying that it should be run in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I can see.

`%` is a default alias for `ForEach-Object` which is a core cmdlet. `foreach -parallel` within workflows is a workflow activity that is separate form the cmdlet and only callable within workflows. In this case, you would need to set an alias to `foreach -parallel` in your workflow to call the workflow activity - but manipulating aliases is disallowed within workflows ([source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/08/21/powershell-workflow-for-mere-mortals-part-3.aspx)).